# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report! - Oct 2017

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, monthly

## Welcome Our SharePoint Stack Exchange Valued Contributors.

We would like to share with you the **Most Active Contributors Report** over the last month!

[image]

**This report includes the following awards:**

1. Monthly Leader Board.
2. Most Active Contributors Award.
3. Most Active Editors Award.
4. Most Active Voters Award.
5. Most Close Votes Review Award.
6. Most First Post Review Award.
7. Most Late Answer Review Award.
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.
9. Most Reopen Review Award.
10. Most Suggested Edit Review Award.
11. Highest Votes Questions Award.
12. Highest Votes Answers Award.
13. Most Viewed Questions Award.
14. 1st Top Contributors summary list.

---

[image]

[image]

You can find the full list at [Stack Exchange Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/105/month/sharepoint/2017-10-02)

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                   REPUTATION
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                   1,676
2   Amal Hashim                856
3   sathish                    530
4   Gautam Sheth               480
5   Waqas Sarwar MVP           470
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                    EDITS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                   128
2   Ronak Patel                46
3   Amal Hashim                35
4   Waqas Sarwar MVP           20
5   Aakash Morya               16
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     VOTES
----------------------------------------------------------
1   sathish                     230
2   Archiever SP                164
3   Desire                      125
4   Well                        111
5   M.Qassas                    91
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Gaurravs                     18
2   M.Qassas                     16
3   Aakash Morya                 12
4   P S                          12
5   Gautam Sheth                 12
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Gaurravs                     80
2   P S                          47
3   Gautam Sheth                 46
4   M.Qassas                     40
5   Aakash Morya                 39
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Gaurravs                    39
2   P S                         18
3   Aakash Morya                17
4   Gautam Sheth                16
5   M.Qassas                    12
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Gaurravs                    38
2   P S                         34
3   Gautam Sheth                31
4   M.Qassas                    27
5   Asad Refai                  21
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Gaurravs                     6
2   Gautam Sheth                 6
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Gaurravs                     32
2   M.Qassas                     22
3   Aakash Morya                 17
4   P S                          17
5   Gautam Sheth                 14
```

---

[image]

1. [Office 365 Security & Compliance Content Search not finding Keyword if among multi-selected Lookup column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228155/office-365-security-compliance-content-search-not-finding-keyword-if-among-mul)

   - **Quest Owner:** Jim Bob Howard.
   - **Votes:** 6.
2. [Limitations of SharePoint OOTB forms against infopath](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/229000/limitations-of-sharepoint-ootb-forms-against-infopath)

   - **Quest Owner:** Rinu.
   - **Votes:** 5.
3. [sharedWithUsersId not returning up to date user ids](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228137/sharedwithusersid-not-returning-up-to-date-user-ids)

   - **Quest Owner:** aioobe.
   - **Votes:** 5.

---

[image]

1. [Is there a way to restrict items from being submitted if it misses a deadline date?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228499/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-items-from-being-submitted-if-it-misses-a-deadline-da/228500#228500)

   - **Answer Owner:** M.Qassas.
   - **Votes:** 9.
2. [SharePoint Online List Items update using PowerShell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228801/sharepoint-online-list-items-update-using-powershell/228805#228805)

   - **Answer Owner:** Mike2500.
   - **Votes:** 6.
3. [CamlQuery that traverses multiple folders](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/229960/camlquery-that-traverses-multiple-folders/229963#229963)

   - **Answer Owner:** M.Qassas.
   - **Votes:** 6.

---

[image]

1. [Is there a way to restrict items from being submitted if it misses a deadline date?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228499/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-items-from-being-submitted-if-it-misses-a-deadline-da/228500#228500)

   - **Views:** 348.
2. [workbench page shows “This site can’t provide a secure connection” on creating SPFx Webpart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/229327/workbench-page-shows-this-site-can-t-provide-a-secure-connection-on-creating-s)

   - **Views:** 181.
3. [Limitations of SharePoint OOTB forms against infopath](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/229000/limitations-of-sharepoint-ootb-forms-against-infopath)

   - **Views:** 174.

---

[image]

1. **Most Active Contributors Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
2. **Most Active Editors Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas)  Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
3. **Most Active Voters Award.**

   - [sathish](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/70026/sathish) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
4. **Most Close Votes Review Award.**

   - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
5. **Most First Post Review Award.**

   - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
6. **Most Late Answer Review Award.**

   - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
7. **Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.**

   - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs)  Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
8. **Most Reopen Review Award.**

   - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
9. **Most Suggested Edit Review Award.**

   - [Gaurravs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20302/gaurravs) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
10. **Highest Votes Questions Award.**

    - [Jim Bob Howard](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/2081/jim-bob-howard) Great Question, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
11. **Highest Votes Answers Award.**

    - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Answer, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
12. **Most Viewed Questions Award.**

    - [Is there a way to restrict items from being submitted if it misses a deadline date?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228499/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-items-from-being-submitted-if-it-misses-a-deadline-da/228500#228500)

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering, We fully appreciate all the great contributions of SharePoint SE members.

> **P.S.:** This report will be published Monthly / Quarterly / Yearly. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback & precious suggestion!